# html page consist lines of php code

Tags: php

i am trying to write a simple login page in client side - html , and server side - php . The following code runs in my virtual machine-kali linux .
When i run login.html file i get the code in php(the commands and all i wrote) with the login format(the format is ok) but the php code is appearing and doesn't run. i've tried EVERYTHING! please can you tell me what is the problem?

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
    session_start(); 

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        $logins = array("nombre" => "1234","name1" => "pass1");
        //prompt from user
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : "error";
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : "error";
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
        $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;
        } else {            
            $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
        }
      }
    ?>
   <b>
     <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <br>
    <form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
      <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="Table">

        <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="top">Username</td>
          <td><input name="Username" type="text" class="Input"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Password</td> 
          <td><input name="Password" type="password" class="Input"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to rename it to login.php and ensure that you have php installed.
Code it self seems to be ok

[eval](https://eval.in/594323)